# MySQL Spatial Extensions: Getting records that fall with in a certain area

Tags: mysql, gis

I am wanting to use the MySQL spartial extension for a project. What it is a javascript viewer will send the edges of the viewable area so the most weaterly, easterly and north and sothern points as the appropriate cordiates(latitude and logitude). I have come accors examples using doing distance caclulation and distance from. However I am only wanting to pluck out the records that would be points with in the viewable area for the user. With the mysql spartial extension say if I have:

name: varchar
location: point
long: double
lat: double

(The long and lat is for ploting the point)

Given the small example table, how would i pull out points with in a viewable area

The folowing link shows how it is done in postgresql. However need it for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the 'geometry' mysql extension.
If your location is of type 'geometry' you could do such a query

```
SELECT *, AsWKT(location) as geomWKT
FROM myTable
WHERE Intersects(location,GeomFromText('POINT(1.9845 49.8543)'))
```

Some examples about the format [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

Comment: [link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Dynamic_KML) The link is for one on postgre sql

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to compute the spatial index yourself. A spatial index is just a space-filling-curve reducing your 2D problem to a 1D problem and thus make it easier to understand. Instead of picking the spatial index most likely you can pick a nested-string-key from the sfc or quadtree. The nested-key is read from the left to the right and the query for similar keys or lat/lng pairs is hence just a string comparision with every operator possible. I have done a sfc implementation in php at phpclasses.org ( hilbert-curve ). Most likely you want to download it! Or most likely you want to search google for Nick's blog spatial index hilbert curve and quadtree.